# Finding an object by it's unique id in Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, firebase

I have a question. Firebase seems to generate unique id's for objects created with the push() method. While that's amazing, the official tutorial seems to omit such a simple question as to how to *retrieve* such an object based on it's unique id.

```
{
  "contacts" : {
    "-KD3p6kdEUbg38X7Osfm" : {
    "address" : "Whitley rd 22, Northampton",
    "email" : "somethingsatsomething@soso",
    "name" : "George Booney",
    "notes" : "Sounds like a serious businessman",
    "phone" : "01239485764",
    "website" : "http://www.workingatthepumps.com"
 },
   "-KD3pzA_P3pK0TCzg4zw" : {
    "address" : "Common Avenue 22, Birmingham",
    "email" : "johnyoeias@nowhereas.com",
    "name" : "John Doe",
    "notes" : "Sounds like a serious businessman",
    "phone" : "44582314864",
    "website" : "http://www.wearelost.com"
}
}
}
```

The code to invoke it looks like this:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://contactsmgr.firebaseIO.com/contacts");

        return {
            get: function() {
             return ref;   
            },
            find: function() {
            // the required code to refer to the unique id
            }
        };
```

Is there a simple way to do this, or is the JSON structure that I have created inherently wrong?

Comment: Hi, if you have the key, you can access like this ref.child('-KD3pzA_P3pK0TCzg4zw'). If not, and you need to look by name or email then you can use orderBy and startAt and endAt. If this is not clear, let me know, to expand the answer. Hope this helps, Regards!

Comment: @KN_ Thank you for the fast reply! Unfortunately, when I attempt to attach it to a model (using angularjs, in my case it's $scope.contact = Contact.find(); ) the model does not display any of the properties...

Comment: If the object doesn't have properties, but it exists, might be that the object is not populated yet. What result do you get from ref.once('value')? Regards!

Comment: What unique ID are you trying to listen to here? As @KN_ says: once you know the unique ID it's a simple lookup: `$scope.contact = $firebaseObject(ref.child('-KD3pzA_P3pK0TCzg4zw'))`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Turns out I have forgotten to place the child() method as an argument of the $firebaseObject service. Seems to be working well now, thank you!

Comment: @KN_ sounds like your comment was the correct answer. Feel like turning it into an answer (with my edits)?

Comment: Hi, I'm glad to hear that worked! @FrankvanPuffelen, Thanks, I'll do it. Regards!

Comment: @KN_ One thing is off though - when I try using the $firebaseObject(ref.orderByChild('phone').startAt('01239485764').endAt('01239485‌​764')); It does not attatch itself to the $scope unlike the first. What's weird is that I see the object succesfuly being returned in the console though

Comment: @Abbadiah. Hi! I would need to see the whole code, to be able to tell you an exact answer, but If you are doing what Frank said, you might have it on the scope already. Check this (if you havent) https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-objects.html, it explains synchronized objects. Regards!!

Comment: @KN_ Thanks a lot for the link! Not only it turns out you can pass unique id with $id service(just caught it as $routeParams.id afterwards), it also has the handy $remove service too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the key, you can access like this `ref.child(id)`.

As @FrankvanPuffelen clarified, you then bind that to your AngularJS scope with:

```
$scope.contact = $firebaseObject(ref.child('-KD3pzA_P3pK0TCzg4zw'));
```

If you do not have the key yet, and you need to look by name or email then you can use `orderBy` and `startAt` and `endAt`:

```
ref.orderByChild('phone').startAt('01239485764').endAt('01239485764');
```